# Label Individual Lines in Seaborn Lineplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I have the followed dataframe:

[image]

I then use this code to generate the plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
sns.lineplot(x="Minutes", y="Hours", data=df1, hue="Product")
plt.show()
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Rather than have the label for each line in the legend, how do I get them to appear on the plot itself i.e. slightly to the right of each individual/associated line or tethered in some way to each line?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this are the options to position the legend in the plot:
Best          0
Upper right   1
Upper left    2
Lower left    3
Lower right   4
Right         5
Center left   6
Center right  7
Lower center  8
Upper center  9
center       10

So I think it´s not posible to do what you ask for.